# Getting Castle Windsor DI & FluentNhibernate Sample to Run

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, fluent-nhibernate, castle-windsor

Hi I downloaded some sample code that uses these 2 libraries for Ioc and repositories.
I am not very experienced in either of these, but have used other types of libraries for this sort of thing.  I just want the sample to run so I can check out some other code features.
The sample says to just change my web.config and then do a "run /boot"

I changed my web.config, but I have no idea what a run /boot is.  Do I have to download some Castle .exe and run some configurtion?

Comment: Probably just means press F5 in Visual Studio to run your code

Comment: actually had to start the application running the url http://localhost/boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a BootController class.  so going to the project settings and making the website startup hitting the url localhost/boot got the thing to load up all this Windsor, FluentNHibernate & Automapper.  That created the tables in the db which allowed the app to run.